# Why Intersection function not showing correct Result?

Tags: python, set

```
A = [1,2,4,6,7,8]
B = [1,3,4,5,6]

U = []
I = []

#A union B
def union(A, B):
    U = A
    for element in B:
        if element not in A:
            U.append(element)
    print("The union of A and B is: ", U)
union(A, B)

#A intersection B
def inters(A, B):
    for element in A:
        if element in B:
            I.append(element)
        else:
            pass
    print("The intersection of A and B is: ", I)
inters(A, B)
```

Comment: Why not use the builtin [`set`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#set), which has `union` and `intersection` methods (and operators `|` and `&`, respectively) defined?

Comment: @Soham have a look https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers

Answer (score 2):

The reason is, you've already updated the list element of A when you this `U = A` because it does not make a copy of **A** it makes reference/another name for **A**, If you check the value of `print(A, I)` **after the first call of** `union(A,B)` then you will understand the effect of it. The **A** also gets updated by this line `U.append(element)` because of `U=A`.

So to fix that, you can replace `U=A` by `U = A.copy()` or `U = A[:]` to do **shallow copy** instead of **reference/aliasing**

```
A = [1,2,4,6,7,8]
B = [1,3,4,5,6]

U = []
I = []

#A union B
def union(A, B):
    U = A  # you are referencing the A by U 
    for element in B:
        if element not in A:
            U.append(element)
    print("The union of A and B is: ", U)


print(A,I) # will return [1, 2, 4, 6, 7, 8, 3, 5] [1, 3, 4, 5, 6] so itersections works as expected.

#A intersection B
def inters(A, B):
    for element in A:
        if element in B:
            I.append(element)
        else:
            pass
    print("The intersection of A and B is: ", I)
```

Comment: Thank you! Got it

Answer (score 2):

After

```
U = A
```

in the `union` call, `U` is just another local reference to set `A` (side note: the global variable `U` is unaffected by this assignment). Now you are adding all the elements from `B` to it, effectively turning `A` into the union of `A` and `B`.

To fix this you should make a shallow copy instead (and probably avoid global variables alltogether):

```
def union(A, B):
    U = A[:]  # shallow copy, not reference!
    for element in B:
        if element not in A:
            U.append(element)
    return U  # makes the function much more useful!
    

def inters(A, B):
    I = []  # make a new list each time!
    for element in A:
        if element in B:
            I.append(element)
    return I  # dito


A = [1,2,4,6,7,8]
B = [1,3,4,5,6]

print("The union of A and B is: ", union(A, B))
print("The intersection of A and B is: ", inters(A, B))
```

Of course, there are many more concise ways to get unions and intersections, unsurprisingly the cleanest are offered by the `set` type:

```
def union(A, B):
    return [*set(A).union(B)]
    # return list(set(A) | set(B))
    # ... more ways to skin this cat

def inters(A, B):
    return [*set(A).intersection(B)]
    # return list(set(A) & set(B))
```

Comment: Thank you! Got it

Answer (score 2):

In `union`, `U = A` does not make a copy of `A`; it makes `U` another name for `A`. That means you've added every element of `B` to `A`, so that by the time you call `inters`, you are computing the intersection of `B` and the union of (the original) `A` and `B`, which is, of course, `B`.

Don't use global variables in your functions, and make a proper copy of `A` in `union`.

```
A = [1,2,4,6,7,8]
B = [1,3,4,5,6]

def union(A, B):
    U = A[:]
    for element in B:
        if element not in U:
            U.append(element)
    print("The union of A and B is: ", U)
    return U

U = union(A, B)

#A intersection B
def inters(A, B):
    I = []
    for element in A:
        if element in B:
            I.append(element)
    print("The intersection of A and B is: ", I)
    return I

I = inters(A, B)
```

Comment: Thank you! Got it